# Rect not covering the parent svg height?

Tags: css, svg

I have the following code:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <rect x=0 y=0 width=1920 height=1080 />
</svg>
```

Why does the rect cover the full width of its parent svg in units? but not the height?

Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reverent-glitter-k60mru?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[image]

Comment: because the aspect ratio of the viewBox does not match the aspect ratio of its container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the dimensions you are using.

What you have is a rectangle inside a square:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <rect x=0 y=0 width=1920 height=1080 />
</svg>
```

When what you should consider is changing your viewBox to being the same height/width ratio as the parent SVG (either all 1920 or all 1080)

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1080 1080">
  <rect x=0 y=0 width=1080 height=1080 />
</svg>
```

Alternatively, you could change the SVG dimensions

```html
<svg width="192" height="108" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <rect x=0 y=0 width=1920 height=1080 />
</svg>
```